# how can I rollback with spring jdbctemplate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, transactions

This is my dao layer:

```
public class UserDAOImpl extends BaseDAO implements UserDAO {

        private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

        public void setTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
            this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
        }

        @Override
        public int storeSignUp(final StoreSignUp store) throws POSException {
            KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
            TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
            TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);
            int id = 0;
            try {
                this.jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_STORE, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                        ps.setString(1, store.getName());
                        ps.setString(2, store.getZip());
                        ps.setString(3, store.getCity());
                        ps.setString(4, store.getState());
                        ps.setInt(5, store.getCountryCode());
                        ps.setString(6, store.getAddress());
                        return ps;
                    }

                }, keyHolder);

                store.setId(keyHolder.getKey().intValue());
                id = store.getId();

                this.jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_STORE_PHONE,
                        new Object[] { store.getId(), store.getPhone(), store.getPassword(), store.getSalt() });
                transactionManager.commit(status);
            } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
                transactionManager.rollback(status);
            }
            return id;
        }
    }
```

This is my application.xml

```
<!-- Initialization for TransactionManager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
`com.data.dao.UserDAOImpl.storeSignUp(UserDAOImpl.java:91)`
```

When i call this method tha data insert into one table but not in
another table so i want to be rollback from first table.

Comment: You have to add the @Autowire Annotation to the transaction manager

Answer (score 1):

This much should be enough for you - `@Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class})`

where `@Transactional` is `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`

Provided you put in on a `public` method , don't eat up `Exception` in that public method and also since you are using xml configuration so make sure that you have ,

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

where `tx` is - `xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"`

This way you will get rid of explicit commit and rollback boiler plate code around - `TransactionDefinition` , `TransactionStatus` etc. 
This becomes cumbersome if needed in multiple methods.